# Wordpress List Pages and their Post Thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress

Needing help on listing the pages I have in wordpress and their 1st depth Child sub pages, with their post thumbnails (or featured image). Also, want to exclude specific pages from being listed

I looked at wp_list_pages(); but see no way of including Post thumbnails

Edit: Thanks Andy, however I can't find an appropriate example of how to use the code to do so. Sorry, very green to php and using it with wordpress.

Comment: I think you'll need to write a custom piece of code to accomplish this. You could do it utilizing https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail most likely. Start with a `get_pages()`, run a foreach and get the page ID, then add your page ID to `get_the_post_thumbnail()`, and output what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$pages = array();
$exclude = '1,2,3'; // Page id of the pages you want to exclude

$args = array(
    'exclude' => $exclude,
    'parent' => 0,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$parents = get_pages( $args );

foreach( $parents as $parent )
{
    $parent -> thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $parent -> ID, 'thumbnail');

    $args = array(
        'exclude' => $exclude,
        'child_of' => $parent -> ID,
        'number' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $child = get_pages( $args );

    $pages[] = $parent;
    if( count( $child ) )
    {
        $child[0] -> thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $child[0] -> ID, 'thumbnail');
        $pages[] = $child[0];
    }
}

print_r( $pages );
```

Comment: Thanks, haven't been able to test yet, but will try this.